# MySQL view with union not working after trying bug fix

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql 5.6 view that needs a union.  I read here on stack overflow there is a server bug using union in a view.  The solution is to remove parenthesis in the from.  I did that but it is not working and was hoping someone can help me get by the bug somehow.

I have 2 tables ordersuccess and orderfailure.  the view calculates a percentage of success for that time period.  The time period is every 15m, 4 per hour, 15,30,45,00.  Here is schema, both are the same.  A count of 0 is not added to the table.  A null can be 0 or 100 depending on the ifnull statement.

`+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id      | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| dtime   | datetime   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| counter | bigint(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| rate    | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+`

I have a calendar table to fill in the blanks when nothing is reported during a period.  It only has date/times for each period.  Here is calendar table;

`+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| dtime | datetime | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+`

Here is the query returning the correct data.

```
 select 
'1000591' AS `id`, 
`c`.`dtime` AS `dtime`, 
'0' AS `rate`, 
ifnull(`p`.`percent`,100) AS `counter`  
from 
(`calendar` `c` left join 
        (   
select 
    ifnull(f.dtime,s.dtime) as dtime,
    ifnull(ifnull(s.counter,0)/(ifnull(s.counter,0) + ifnull(f.counter,0)) * 100,100) as percent 
    from 
        (select * from OrderSummarySuccess_14521 where id = 1000591) s 
            right join 
        (select * from OrderSummaryFailure_14521 where id = 1000591) f 
        on s.dtime=f.dtime 
union 
select 
    ifnull(f.dtime,s.dtime) as dtime,
    ifnull(ifnull(s.counter,0)/(ifnull(s.counter,0) + ifnull(f.counter,0)) * 100,100) as percent 
    from 
        (select * from OrderSummarySuccess_14521 where id = 1000591) s 
            left join 
        (select * from OrderSummaryFailure_14521 where id = 1000591) f 
        on s.dtime=f.dtime 
    order by dtime  
        ) `p` 
        on((`c`.`dtime` = `p`.`dtime`))
) 
where c.dtime < now()`
```

I have to make multiple views due to having selects in the from clause.  Here are my create view for this query.  I removed all of the parenthesis I could.  Did I miss something or is there a better way to write the query?

`CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=root@localhost SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW d61_14521 AS 
         select '1000591' AS id,
         c.dtime AS dtime,
         0 AS rate,
         ifnull(p.percent,100) AS counter 
         from calendar c left join d61p2_14521 p on c.dtime = p.dtime;`

`CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=root@localhost SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
         VIEW d61P2_14521 AS select 
    '1000591' AS id, 
    c.dtime AS dtime, 
    '0' AS rate, 
    ifnull(p.percent,100) AS counter

    from 
    d61P3_14521 
    union 
    d61P6_14521
    where c.dtime < now();`

`CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=root@localhost SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
         VIEW d61P3_14521 AS select 
        ifnull(f.dtime,s.dtime) as dtime,
        ifnull(ifnull(s.counter,0)/(ifnull(s.counter,0) + ifnull(f.counter,0)) * 100,100) as percent 
        from 
            d61P4_14521 s 
                right join 
            d61P5_14521 f 
            on s.dtime=f.dtime ;`

`CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=root@localhost SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
         VIEW d61P4_14521 AS select * from OrderSummarySuccess_14521 where id = 1000591 ;`

`CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=root@localhost SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
         VIEW d61P5_14521 AS select * from OrderSummaryFailure_14521 where id = 1000591;`

`CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=root@localhost SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
         VIEW d61P6_14521 AS select 
        ifnull(f.dtime,s.dtime) as dtime,
        ifnull(ifnull(s.counter,0)/(ifnull(s.counter,0) + ifnull(f.counter,0)) * 100,100) as percent 
        from 
            d61P4_14521 s 
                left join 
            d61P5_14521 f 
            on s.dtime=f.dtime ;`

I create the views in this order.  They succeed until d61P2_14521.

1. d61P4_14521
2. d61P5_14521
3. d61P6_14521
4. d61P3_14521
5. d61P2_14521

The view that fails is d61P2_14521. Here is the error.

`mysql> CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=root@localhost SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    ->  VIEW d61P2_14521 AS select
    -> '1000591' AS id,
    -> c.dtime AS dtime,
    -> '0' AS rate,
    -> ifnull(p.percent,100) AS counter
    -> from
    -> d61P3_14521
    -> union
    -> d61P6_14521
    -> where c.dtime < now();
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'vod61P6_14521
where c.dtime < now()' at line 10`

Comment: union is for select statements, not joins. it's `select ... UNION select ...`. doing `select ... join foo UNION bar` is illegal/impossible.

Comment: I used the same syntax in the working query and the query works.  its the only way I know how to do a full outer join in mysql.

Comment: no, you didn't. in your "working" query, you have `select ... union select ...`. Just because a view is a stored `select` doesn't mean you use the view's name in place of a select.

Comment: You have two errors there: you cannot ommit `on` when using `left join` (that is only allowed, yet not recommended, with a pure `join`, and that is the problem your error message is complaining about right now). And a `union` is not a join. It combines rows. So you have to do something like `union select ...`, and that select has to have the same number of columns as the upper part.

Comment: Thanks Marc for responding I appreciate your help.  i have used view inside a view this way before and got the expected results.  I can't use a select in a from clause inside a view is the reason I use the view in this way. Can you show me the correct way?

Comment: Thanks Solarflare for responding.  I will have to change the query to be able to use the on.  I'll do that and test.  I'm trying to do a full outer join which is why I used the union.  I used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql  I get the expected results using the query that is not a view.

Comment: I can guarantee you that your query didn't work that way outside a view, your error has nothing to do with a view. But i think I finally understood what you are trying to do: instead of `... AS counter from d61P3_14521 
union d61P6_14521 where c.dtime < now();` use `... as counter from 
calendar c left join (select * from d61P3_14521 union select * from d61P6_14521) as p on (c.dtime = p.dtime)  where c.dtime < now();` (assuming `d61P6_14521` and `d61P3_14521` have the same structure, otherwise you have to specify the columns instead of using `*` there).

Comment: thanks for responding, If I put the selects inside a from I get this error. ERROR 1349 (HY000): View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause .  That;s why I'm having to do multiple views.  This technique is used in our legacy system.  This is the first one I've need to do a full outer join.  The only way I know how to do that is using union.  I'm trying to come up with an alternate query without a union.

Comment: Ah, ok, I overlooked the `5.6`. If you can't update your server, you have to use another view: `create view abc1233 as select * from d61P3_14521 union select * from d61P6_14521` and then use `... as counter from calendar c left join abc1233 as p on (c.dtime = p.dtime) where c.dtime < now();`

Comment: thank you Solarflare that did the trick.  I was close but needed to make the union its own view.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Solarflare can you write up a mini answer so we can sprinkle some points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until MySQL 5.7.7, you cannot use subqueries in from-clauses (or join-clauses) of a view. So you have to move these subqueries in seperate views. Your query can (after a little clean up) be split into 2 views:

```
create viewSubqueryFullOuterJoin as
  select 
    ifnull(f.dtime,s.dtime) as dtime,
    ifnull(ifnull(s.counter,0)/(ifnull(s.counter,0) 
        + ifnull(f.counter,0)) * 100,100) as percent 
  from OrderSummarySuccess_14521 s
  right join OrderSummaryFailure_14521 f 
  on s.id = 1000591 and f.id = 1000591 and s.dtime=f.dtime 
union 
  select 
    ifnull(f.dtime,s.dtime) as dtime,
    ifnull(ifnull(s.counter,0)/(ifnull(s.counter,0) 
         + ifnull(f.counter,0)) * 100,100) as percent 
  from OrderSummarySuccess_14521 s 
  left join OrderSummaryFailure_14521 f 
  on s.id = 1000591 and f.id = 1000591 and s.dtime=f.dtime
order by dtime;  -- 'order by' might belong in viewQueryWithSubquery

create viewQueryWithSubquery as
select 
  '1000591' AS `id`, 
  `c`.`dtime` AS `dtime`, 
  '0' AS `rate`, 
  ifnull(`p`.`percent`,100) AS `counter`  
from `calendar` `c` 
left join viewSubqueryFullOuterJoin `p`
on `c`.`dtime` = `p`.`dtime`
where `c`.dtime < now();
```